# Making dynamic graphs in python's Networkx

Tags: python, dynamic, graph, timestamp, networkx

I am trying to make a dynamic graph using networkx. For example when I use:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
```

it makes an empty graph G which is by default static. How can I change it to dynamic? Some nodes/edges may exist in one timestamp but not in the others. How can I incorporate time?
As an example, suppose my graph has three nodes 'a', 'b' and 'c'. At time t1, there is only one edge between 'a' and 'b'. At time t2 the configuration of edges changes and in this timestamp all nodes are connected to each other. Say:

```
G.add_edge('a','b',timestamp='t1')
G.add_node('c',timestamp='t1')

G.add_edge('a','b',timestamp='t2')
G.add_edge('a','c',timestamp='t2')
G.add_edge('b','c',timestamp='t2')
```

but this does not work!

the reason I need to do this is that I want to save the graph in gexf format to use it in Gephi.

What should I do?

Comment: So do you have a completely different graph at each time, or are only some edges and some nodes changing?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, Joel. Yes that should be "nodes"! This is one graph which evolves by time. It may gain/lose nodes or edges.

Comment: "DyNetx is a Python software package that extends networkx with dynamic network models and algorithms": https://dynetx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 4):

Using `nx.Graph()` you cannot have more than one edge between 2 nodes. 
However if you use `nx.MultiGraph()` you can.

What you can do is index the node of the graph with a simple counter as set the node ID and timestamp as a property. You would have to filter the node based on their property if you want to select a subset using `nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'id')`.

In a general manner, NetworkX is not made for dynamic graphs. You can use [Stinger](http://www.stingergraph.com/) which is designed exactly for that.

EDIT: For Gephi, it is completely different. You should export the graph in GEXF and pray for Gephi to read it. Basically something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gexf xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft" version="1.2" xmlns:viz="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft/viz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft/gexf.xsd">
  <meta lastmodifieddate="2016-01-07">
    <creator>Gephi 0.8.1</creator>
    <description></description>
  </meta>
  <graph defaultedgetype="directed" timeformat="double" mode="dynamic">
    <attributes class="node" mode="dynamic">
      <attribute id="score" title="score" type="integer"></attribute>
    </attributes>
    <attributes class="edge" mode="dynamic">
      <attribute id="weight" title="Weight" type="float"></attribute>
    </attributes>
    <nodes>
      <node id="n0" label="n0" start="2001.0" end="2022.0">
        <attvalues>
          <attvalue for="score" value="4" start="2001.0" end="2010.0"></attvalue>
          <attvalue for="score" value="3" start="2011.0" end="2011.0"></attvalue>
        </attvalues>
        <viz:size value="10.0"></viz:size>
        <viz:position x="46.152466" y="-287.68558" z="0.0"></viz:position>
        <viz:color r="25" g="213" b="100"></viz:color>
      </node>
      <node id="n1" label="n1" start="2001.0" end="2024.0">
        <attvalues>
          <attvalue for="score" value="2" start="2001.0" end="2007.0"></attvalue>
          <attvalue for="score" value="3" start="2008.0" end="2008.0"></attvalue>
        </attvalues>
        <viz:size value="10.0"></viz:size>
        <viz:position x="-293.90674" y="-442.9504" z="0.0"></viz:position>
        <viz:color r="25" g="213" b="100"></viz:color>
      </node>
    </nodes>
    <edges>
      <edge source="n0" target="n1">
        <attvalues>
          <attvalue for="weight" value="3.0" start="2010.0" endopen="2012.0"></attvalue>
          <attvalue for="weight" value="4.0" start="2012.0" endopen="2014.0"></attvalue>
          <attvalue for="weight" value="4.0" start="2014.0" endopen="2016.0"></attvalue>
          <attvalue for="weight" value="4.0" start="2016.0" endopen="2018.0"></attvalue>
          <attvalue for="weight" value="5.0" start="2018.0" endopen="2020.0"></attvalue>
          <attvalue for="weight" value="6.0" start="2020.0" endopen="2022.0"></attvalue>
          <attvalue for="weight" value="8.0" start="2022.0" endopen="2024.0"></attvalue>
          <attvalue for="weight" value="9.0" start="2024.0" end="2026.0"></attvalue>
        </attvalues>
      </edge>
    </edges>
  </graph>
</gexf>
```

I am not sure you can directly achieve that with Networkx. [People have tried](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/networkx-discuss/a1PWAVghc44). What is important is that an edge should have a `start` and `end` property as double. Same for nodes. Then each edge should have a list of triplets:

```
[{'start': s, 'end' or 'endopen': e, 'weight': 4}, {..}]
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the reason I need to do this is that I need to save the graph in gexf format to use it in Gephi. If I use property to represent timestamp and save it as gexf, Gephi does not recognize it as a "dynamic" graph.

Comment: Your question does not mention Gephi. I will modify the answer.

Comment: Yes I tried that before. But I cant make anything like 

timeformat="double" mode="dynamic" 

in a graph make by networkx.
I also tried to import a Gephi's dynamic gexf into python so I might be able to figure it about, but networkx doesnt recognize it!

Comment: You would probably have to modify the gexf parser in networkx to achieve that. Because Networkx uses gexf 1.1 and Gephi 1.2draft. I can import the graph in networkx but when I output it the format changes, notably for start and end properties on nodes.

Answer (score 0):

DyNetx, a Python software package built on NetworkX, extends existing capabilities by offering dynamic network models and algorithms specifically designed for describing, modeling, and studying the complexities of social, biological, and infrastructure networks that evolve over time.

Check out the [tutorial](https://dynetx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).

For example, given a CSV file with `Source,Target,Time` columns ([the file I’ve used is here](https://pastebin.com/gf3fDay9)), and assuming the `Time` column is filled with non-uniformly random increasing integers, the following code will output some interesting basic analysis and visualizations:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import dynetx as dn

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("SourceTargetTime.csv")

# Creating the dynamic directed graph
g = dn.DynDiGraph(edge_removal=True)

max_time = max(df.Time)
def add_interaction(row, endt=max_time+1):
    # the edges will exist at [t, e)
    g.add_interaction(u=row['Source'], v=row['Target'], t=row['Time'], e=endt)

df.apply(add_interaction, axis=1);

t=8
print(f'The number of interactions at t={t}: ', g.number_of_interactions(t=t))

snapshot_ids = g.temporal_snapshots_ids()

times = range(min(snapshot_ids), max(snapshot_ids)+1)
num_interactions = [g.number_of_interactions(t=snapshot_id) for snapshot_id in times]
plt.plot(times, num_interactions)
plt.xlabel("Times")
plt.ylabel("Number of Interactions")
plt.title("Number of Interactions vs. Time")
plt.show()

degree_stats = []
for t in times:
    tdegrees = tuple(g.degree(t=t).values())
    degree_stats.append(np.quantile(tdegrees, (0.5, 1)))
plt.plot(times, degree_stats)
plt.xlabel("Times")
plt.ylabel("Degree")
plt.title("Max & Median Degree vs. Time")
plt.show()

edge_times = nx.get_edge_attributes(g,'t')  # returns a dict: (n1, n2): [[t,e], ...]
# red: earlier interactions
# green: 0
# blue: number of occurences of the interactions
edge_colors = 1-np.array([(te_pairs[0][0]/max_time, 1, 1/len(te_pairs)) for te_pairs in edge_times.values()])

nx.draw(g, edge_color=edge_colors, width=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: Number of Interactions vs. Time]
[image: Max & Median Degree vs. Time]
[image: Graph plot with edge colors based on interactions properties]