# How to create a temporal network using Networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, temporal

I have this dataset that contains the Source, Target and timestamp. How to create a graph with timestamp using python (Networkx)?

| Source | Target | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4/15/04 2:56PM |
| 3 | 4 | 4/16/04 10:50PM |
| 5 | 2 | 4/19/04 10:39PM |
| 6 | 7 | 4/20/04 5:40PM |
| 8 | 7 | 4/20/04 5:42PM |
| 9 | 10 | 4/20/04 5:53PM |
| ... | ... | ... |

anyone can help me?

for a static network, I can create the network. But, I cannot construct a dynamic/interactive network, where the network connections change according to day.

dataset source: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZAvnBj68Y_N2nV9csfrXAPjQuNMdlqom/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Similar to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646956/making-dynamic-graphs-in-pythons-networkx), they seem to refer to an extension package that adds support for dynamic networks (see [here](https://dynetx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

If you need to do it 'raw', you might want to create a set of static nodes, separate edges into some bucketed timeframes, and iterate over the timeframes adding edges only for those buckets for current time. Rough and expensive, but might work.

Would also help if you post some code for what you have tried so far as future reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making dynamic graphs in python's Networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646956/making-dynamic-graphs-in-pythons-networkx)
Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77990043/532060) for code and visualizations.

Answer (score 0):

The [networkx-temporal](https://pypi.org/project/networkx-temporal/) package extends NetworkX functions for dynamic graphs. It allows to convert an attributed graph with temporal information embedded in the node or edge-level (such as yours) to a snapshot-based temporal graph, as well as slicing it into a number of bins/steps or time periods.

Although the question mentions NetworkX specifically, it is worth noting that other Python libraries exist for temporal network analysis that are not strictly based on it, such as [DyNetX](https://dynetx.readthedocs.io) and [Teneto](https://teneto.readthedocs.io).

##### 1. Build static graph from file

Let's first build a directed multigraph from the data set using NetworkX's [read_edgelist](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html):

```py
import networkx as nx

file = "CollegeMsg (STUDY DATASET).csv"

# Fiirst two lines from file:
# Source,Target,Timestamp
# 1,2,4/15/04 2:56 PM

with open(file, "r") as f:
    G = nx.read_edgelist(f.readlines()[1:],
                         create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph,
                         data=[("Timestamp", str)],
                         delimiter=",",
                         nodetype=int)

print(f"{G} (mean node degree: {2*G.size()/G.order():.2f})")
```

The result is a `MultiDiGraph with 1899 nodes and 59835 edges (mean node degree: 63.02)`.

##### 2. Build temporal graph object

Now we may use the static graph `G` as input for a temporal graph `TG` to slice it into daily snapshots:

```py
import networkx_temporal as nxt

# Convert dates to YYYY-MM-DD format, allowing to sort them correctly.
to_date = lambda x: datetime\
                    .strptime(x, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")\
                    .strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

TG = nxt.from_static(G).slice(attr="Timestamp",
                              attr_level="edge",
                              apply_func=to_date)
```

The result is a `TemporalMultiDiGraph(t=193)`, i.e., a temporal graph object composed of 193 snapshots.

To verify the daily interval with the highest number of nodes, for example, we can simply check its index:

```
t = TG.order().index(max(TG.order()))

print(f"t={t} ({TG[t].name}) has V={TG[t].order()} nodes and E={TG[t].size()} edges")
```

So we learn that the snapshot at `t=40 (2004-05-27) has V=548 nodes and E=2678 edges`.

##### 3. Describe data set

As the resulting number of snapshots is a bit high to plot all at once, we can gather some insight on the network's temporal dynamics by computing a few statistics with Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"nodes": TG.order(),
                   "edges": TG.size(),
                   "max_in_deg": [
                        max([d[1] for d in deg]) for deg in TG.in_degree()],
                   "max_out_deg": [
                        max([d[1] for d in deg]) for deg in TG.out_degree()],
                   "mean_deg": [
                        sum([d[1] for d in deg])/len(deg) for deg in TG.degree()]})

df.describe().iloc[1:].round(2)

#        nodes    edges     max_in_deg   max_out_deg   mean_deg
# mean   117.01   310.03    18.69        26.60         3.57
# std    120.12   486.86    22.20        31.56         2.25
# min    2.00     1.00      1.00         1.00          1.00
# 25     38.00    45.00     4.00         6.00          2.11
# 50     61.00    94.00     8.00         13.00         2.79
# 75     176.00   269.00    24.00        35.00         4.40
# max    548.00   2678.00   106.00       179.00        10.82
```

We see that the network's activity fluctuates a lot, considering such a high range in the values above, and that the number of nodes and edges on most snapshots is lower than the observed mean. That still does not help us understand the network's evolution, however, so let's try and plot these metrics over time.

##### 4. Visualize activity over time

We can use the same data frame `df` we have just created to draw a [chart of the network's order, size, and node degree centrality over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr9Q6.png), in order to better understand the activity patterns it displays:

> I can't embed images in here yet, so the above link allows to see the resulting figure.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 6), nrows=2, ncols=1, constrained_layout=True)

df.index = TG.names

df.iloc[:, :2].plot(ax=ax[0], color=["#1f77b4cc", "#ff7f0ecc"])
df.iloc[:, 2:4].plot(ax=ax[1], color=["#2ca02ccc", "#d62728cc"])

ax[0].legend(labels=["Total nodes", "Total edges"])
ax[0].set_title(f"Network order, size, and node degree centrality over time ($t$={len(TG)} days)")
ax[0].set_xticklabels([])

ax[1].legend(labels=["Max. in-degree", "Max. out-degree"])
ax[1].set_xlabel("Date")
ax[1].set_xticklabels(ax[1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=10)

for ax_ in ax:
    ax_.grid(color="#cccccc", linestyle="dotted", linewidth=1)
    ax_.set_xticklabels(ax_.get_xticklabels(), rotation=10)
    ax_.set_xlim((0, df.shape[0]))
    ax_.set_ylabel("Value")
```

From the plot, we see that the network grew only over a small amount of time, constantly decreasing in order and size after around June. But at the same time, some of its nodes still exhibit peaks of activity (max. in-/out-degree) that are comparable to earlier in the year, especially around July and September.

We could continue the analysis from then on by relying on specific intervals of interest, for example, or checking out the nodes and edges that most frequently appear considering the daily snapshots.

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the [networkx-temporal](https://pypi.org/project/networkx-temporal/) package, which I started writing when I couldn't find a standardized way to create and unify temporal graphs. Searching online brought me here in the past, so I figured I should add an answer. It has just been released, so contributions are especially welcome!